# How does corda ensures privacy of corda-account if they kept private key and publickey in Nodes database table?

Tags: corda

[image: this is how the table which keep private key and pub key of an account look alike.]

the above picture shows the table which stores the pub key and private key of an account. If this is how it happens then what about the privacy of account is maintained from its Node or is there a way to provide private key from outside the node ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node which hosts the accounts will have full visibilities of the data on the account's sub-vault. You can view the accounts features as an isolation between different accounts, but since they all sit inside the node's vault. The node can see it all.

However, separate the private keys from the parent node is on the future roadmap of account.

For details documentation of account, please view: https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/docs.md